# Android changing a color's brightness

Tags: android, colors

I want to change the brightness of any given color (Note: I am not talking about screen brightness), I have looked at the **Color** class, it has a few methods for conversions between RGB and HSV, I'm a newbie in this area. To start with, how do I change the brightness of red, if its value is spefied in RGB (#FF0000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you need to remember two things -

1. To reduce brightness, you can change red from #FF0000 to #AA0000 or #880000 - basically reduce the Red component.
2. You can also try reducing opacity - often you'll realize that it works better than just reducing brightness.

Comment: I had this idea of varying opacity, how would I reduce the brightness uniformly if I have something like #D456FB?

Comment: #D456FB is equivalent to #FFD456FB, where the first two characters represent opacity. Change it to #99D456FB to get reduced opacity. If you're doing it through code and not through Xml, search for how to increase or decrease 'alpha'.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to convert the color to HSL (not HSV! they are different - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and change the L component - increase to make it brighter, decrease to make it darker.

Comment: Code examples would be better, I was looking at theory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion has a link to code examples.

Comment: It's not true. Here is the way to use HSV to change brightness, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4928826/3109401

Comment: HSL seems to be more appropriate indeed. If you use android support library, you can use `ColorUtils.colorToHSL()` and `ColorUtils.HSLToColor()`   for conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you are talking about **brightness** (color enhance) and not **luminance** (white amount), your model is the HSV (aka HSB) and not HSL.

On fast briefing, if you enhance the V channel on HSV over, lets say... some blue, you have a "more blue" color. If you enhance the L channel on HSL model you have a more "clear and washed" blue.

The android.graphics.Color class have built-in support to HSV model. Use ***Color.colorToHSV()*** and ***Color.HSVToColor()*** to edit the brightness value (or hue, or saturation, if you like).

On HSV model, H (hue) define the base color, S (saturation) control the amount of gray and V controls the brightness. So, if you enhance V and decrease S at same time, you gets more luminance, in pratice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Color.colorToHSV`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#colorToHSV(int,%20float%5B%5D)) to convert the color to HSV, then change the brightness of the HSV color, then use [`Color.HSVToColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#HSVToColor(float%5B%5D)) to convert it back to a color int. For example, the following code sets the brightness to 0.5:

```java
@ColorInt int originalColor = /*your original color*/;
float[] hsv = new float[3];    //Create an array to pass to the colorToHSV function
Color.colorToHSV(originalColor, hsv);    //Put the HSV components in the array created above
hsv[2] = 0.5f;    //Whatever brightness you want to set. 0 is black, 1 is the pure color.
@ColorInt int newColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);    //Convert it back to a ColorInt
```