# Unify Brightness of 2 images

Tags: python, opencv, brightness

I want a way or steps to unify the brightness of 2 images or in other words make their brightness the same but without assigning them. I know how to get the brightness of an image using PIL, the code is found below:

```
from PIL import Image

imag = Image.open("test.png")
# Convert the image te RGB if it is a .gif for example
imag = imag.convert('RGB')
# coordinates of the pixel
X, Y = 0, 0
# Get RGB
pixelRGB = imag.getpixel((X, Y))
R, G, B = pixelRGB
brightness = sum([R, G, B]) / 3  ##0 is dark (black) and 255 is bright (white)
print(brightness)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to make 2 images having the same brightness. Thank you

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/

Comment: @fmw42 yes, i saw it and implemented it on my own, but i was confused on whether this code changes the brightness or is it related to colors only! Cz when analyzing the results my image colors changed completely to different colors(i.e green turned to pink). I expect my results to be only brighter.

Comment: It does both. It matches the mean and standard deviation of the two images (which correspond to brightness and contrast) for each channel of the image separately.  You can force it to only do the brightness and contrast and no color change by converting your images to either HSV or LAB and use only the V or L channels in the processing. Then convert back to RGB.

Comment: @fmw42 Oh okay okay got it! That is a really good idea, thank you for your help!!

Comment: @fmw42 You can add your answer if you want so i can accept it as a right answer

Comment: OK. I posted it as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mean/standard deviation color transfer technique in Python/OpenCV as described at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/. But to force it so as not to modify the color and only adjust the brightness/contrast, convert your image to HSV. Process only the V channel using the method described in that reference. Then combine the new V and old S and H channels and convert that back to BRG.

Comment: I think it's better to adjust brightness/contrast in RGB directly.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/11396782/5987

Comment: `@Mark Ransom`. If you do that channel by channel as per in my reference, you will change the colors. The OP wanted to keep the colors and only change the brightness/contrast.

Comment: If you multiply all 3 channels by the same factor you won't change the color.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But how do you get the same factor. One way is to stack all the channels together into one image. The other is to take the average statistics from each of the channels. So that is certainly one way.