# Darken Toolbar Color for Statusbar in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, toolbar, statusbar

I have different Actionbar (Toolbar) colors in some of my activities.
I get the colors from resources and there are HEX.

```
mToolbar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(CharacterColors[CharID - 1])));
```

How i can generate a darker version of each color for status bar?

For example i want darken my Toolbar color (#34495e) to (#2a3a4b) and set it as my status bar color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using color and color.darker in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928772/using-color-and-color-darker-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a method yourself unlike standard Java as there is a Color.darker() method.

[Check this answer for a working method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928772/android-color-darker).