# Increase Contrast 50% by using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, contrast, camanjs

I'm looking for a formula or something with which i can increase the contrast +50% of the image and can save it.

I have tried Caman.js and its letting me increase contrast by numerical values and I can't figure out what level is 50%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Canvas image contrast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521978/html5-canvas-image-contrast)