# Create a gradient map based on timestamps using php

Tags: php, background-color

I'm trying to create a usefull graph based on a 2dimensional matrix.

Users will click on the intersections of the matrix, fill out some information and hit submit. When this happens I log a timestamp of the event.

I want the admin to be able to graphically intepret this info so what I'd like to do is assign a CSS background colour to each square of the matrix based on when it was clicked. Eg pale blue for the items clicked first and a darker blue.for the items clicked more reciently.

I've been racking my brains but for the life of me I can't figure out a way to do it. The problem is that the clicks could happen in any order at any time.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Above is what Im trying to acheave, the numbers symbolize timestamps (1 being the earliest timestamp and 14 being the most recent)

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 hsl makes this super easy:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-examples

Comment: +1 For a good answer, but HSL Isn't completelty x-broweser supported yet, Maybe add an example implementation and a x-browser reccomendation?

Comment: That looks awesome, the problem is I know the majority of my users are using IE7!! (why they cant upgrade I dont know...)

Can you think of anyway to do it using HEX>? (but +1 for a neat solution)

Comment: Sorry I tend to leave in the present looking forward. I'm sure they are tons of script/js lib to do that. Google gave me this on a neet website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Oki doke,

The way I have chosen to deal with this is to first generate a list of gradient hex values, I generated my gradient from here:

http://www.herethere.net/~samson/php/color_gradient/?cbegin=B5E1FF&cend=00092E&steps=6

I then sorted my array by the timestamps using the subval sort function developed here

http://www.firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/

and then I assign the hex value based on position...

A simple representation of this is here =>

```
<?php
$test = array(
            array("test", 1),
            array("test2", 2),
            array("test4", 4),
            array("test5", 5),
            array("test3", 3),
            array("test6", 6)
            );


function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
    $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
}
asort($b);
foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
    $c[] = $a[$key];
}
return $c;
}

$test2 = subval_sort($test,'1'); 

foreach($test2 as &$t) {
if($t[1]==1){
    array_push($t, "B5E1FF");
    }
elseif($t[1]==2){$t[2]="96BDDC";}
elseif($t[1]==3){$t[2]="7899B9";}
elseif($t[1]==4){$t[2]="5A7596";}
elseif($t[1]==5){$t[2]="3C5173";}
elseif($t[1]==6){$t[2]="1E2C50";}
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test2);
echo"</pre>"; 

?>
```

Can anyone see anything horrendously wrong with this?