# RGB color to HSL bytes

Tags: c++, python, math, rgb, hsl

I've seen some implementations for converting RGB to HSL. Most are accurate and work in both directions.

To me its not important that it will work in 2 directions (no need to put back to RGB)
But i want code that returns values from 0 to 255 max, also for the Hue channel.
And I wouldnt like to do devisions like Hue/360*250 i am searching for integer based math no Dwords  (its for another system), nice would be some kind of boolean logix (and/or/xor)

It should not do any integer or real number based math, the goal is code 
working only using byte math.

Maybe someone already has found such math when he used code like

1. c++ or
2. c# or
3. python

Which i would be able to translate to c++

Comment: possible duplicate of [HSL to RGB color conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the [`colorsys`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html) module, it has methods like:

[`colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r,g,b)`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html#colorsys.rgb_to_hls)

[`colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h,l,s)`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html#colorsys.hls_to_rgb)

Comment: You'll need to divide the inputs and multiply the outputs by 255 but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Well i was more looking for the math then some lib that can do this.
I know routines that do the trick but they all require DWORD or REAL based math. I need something that works on bytes

Answer (score 1):

The [easyrgb](http://www.easyrgb.com) site has many code snippets for color space conversion. Here's the [rgb->hsl](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=18#text18) code.

Comment: yes but i like to do this using byte math (no DWord based math)

Comment: I understand. Are you familiar with scaling? For example, if your floating point numbers have 3 significant digits, multiply the input numbers by 1000, do the integer arithmetic, then integer divide the results by 1000.

Comment: Here's a scaling (fixed point arithmetic) reference starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic