# String concatenation with null's and undefined's in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I always thought that one of the advantages of using this formulation of console.log will save you from null pointer exceptions and the like:

```
var c = undefined;
console.log(c,"foo");

now we get 

"undefined 'foo'"
```

however, there doesn't really seem to be much of an advantage, since using the + operator seems to coerce null's and undefined's into strings before concatenation:

```
var c = undefined;
console.log(c + "foo");
```

this simply logs

```
"undefinedfoo"
```

Is there any way to get a null pointer or some error thrown from concatenating strings with the `+` operator or `console.log(x,y)` in JS? You of course can get a null pointer exception/error doing `undefined.concat('foo')`.

is there any way to get a null point exception when concatenating Strings in JavaScript?

Comment: javascript has no pointers, therefore getting a null pointer exception would essentially be impossible.

Comment: ok, Marc then what happens when you call undefined.concat('');

Comment: "TypeError: undefined has no properties", as you would expect...

Comment: yes because undefined does not point to an object that has a concat function property, touché https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer

Comment: despite what the internet says, it's the same soup, don't believe the hype that "JS doesn't have null pointers"

Comment: by definition, undefined is a null pointer. that's what it is. by definition.

Comment: wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined  it's a defined type: a primitive value.

Comment: Marc, undefined is a type, and that type represents a null pointer. that's the rub, they are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to get a null point exception when concatenating Strings in JavaScript?

**Technically**, *no* (JavaScript doesn't have Null Pointer Exceptions).

**In the spirit of what your'e asking, though**, *yes*.  [ES6 Symbols will actually throw if you try to implicitly coerce them to strings](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/string-symbol). Additionally, you can also intentionally screw around with the implicit `toString()` behavior:

```
var obj = { toString: function() { throw 'uh oh'; } };
console.log(obj + ''); // throws
```

**For day-to-day development, though**, *it's pretty safe* to assume string coercion will succeed. Maybe this will change in future years as Symbols become more ubiquitous, though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: JavaScript doesn't enforce types and handles type conversion a little bit weirdly. It is happy to try to render pretty much anything as a string without complaining.

However, if you want to have JavaScript freak out when a string turns out to be null, you can use assertions. JavaScript doesn't have assertions built-in like many languages do, but [this answer can help you to manually add an assert function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313435/992504). Using that, you could do something like this to enforce that a string not be null:

`assert(typeof myString !== 'undefined')`

Comment: "It is happy to try to render pretty much anything as a string without complaining" This is 99.9999999% accurate. Please see my answer for the .0000001%.

Comment: @jmar777 I knew there had to be something that couldn't be coerced into a string! Oh JavaScript, you strange strange creature.