# HSI, HSL and HSV Difference and their appropriate applications

Tags: image-processing, colors, color-scheme, color-space

I am really confused between the difference of HSI, HSL and HSV. Can someone explain to me their differences in the most simplest way and what will be the scenarios where its more appropriate to choose one among the others?

UPDATE:

I have figured out already the difference between the three in a mathematical way but I am curious what applications thus each of the color models stated above are appropriate?

Comment: This should help... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: @MarkSetchell --> but what applications this colorspaces are appropriate?

Comment: Not sure how rigorous or satisfying this is, but mostly we use HSL/HSV to detect hues (colours) with some degree of tolerance to lighting variation, so we often discard the L/I/B channel anyway which is upsetting you so much. The HSL and HSV models were developed at different times and places which is why there are multiple models. I don't know of any case where you **must** use one over the other.

Comment: They are very handy to construct colourpickers, or perform colour extraction/keying, that being said they don't represent any meaningful perceptual quantities which limit their usage in Colorimetry and Colour Science in general.

Comment: Almost the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20853527/7328782