# How to filter out hue errors in images

Tags: javascript, image, hsl

I've been running a hue difference algorithm on some images. Hue difference generally means difference in color, and only color, regardless of contrast:

[image: hue difference]

But, I've noticed a nasty effect with some images:

[image]

As you can see, cyan and yellow appeared *out of nowhere*. To be totally sure, I have run a test where the hue in the image was set to `1` and lightness to `0.5`:

[image]

The broken colors really seem to be near black/white pixels on *almost every image*. I use [this rgb/hsl algorighm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493060/607407).

During every operation on images before, colorless pixels (lightness = 1 or 0 OR saturation = 0) were treated differently (their undefined color did not affect the calculation).

My questions about the problem:

1. Are the colors real, or is it a bug in RGB/HSL
2. Either way, is it possible to filtrate them out?

Comment: Just curious, would you be able to run this in Python `colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)` and share the output? That could at least narrow down to if it's the algorithm vs to be expected

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to use Python at all. Could you elaborate a little on what should I do?

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. Just curious if you had access to another RGB//HSL converter, so compare outputs