# RGB To HSL Algorithm?

Tags: nxt, nxc

I have seen many algorithms and formulas for converting RGB data to HSL but none were successful.

So where can I get few algorithms/formulas for converting.

Comment: http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=18#text18 check this out.

Comment: If you only need to convert values by hand, then you can use this tool: http://colormaid.com/color-conversion/

Comment: How did you decide it is not working? Are you sure your value ranges are correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HSL to RGB color conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)