# convert hsla to rgba by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, rgba, color-codes

I started learning javascript one month ago. So I dont know that much about pure javascript. I am learning jquery and jquery ui. I am trying to convert hsla values to rgba values. I am using jquery ui slider for picking hsla color. Now I want to convert those jquery ui slider value to rgba value. Here is the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/nbwjk5ag/3/)**. I found some solutions on stackoverflow and on the web. But I don't understand how to use them with jquery ui slider. All of the solutions look like almost same. So, here one of them:

```
/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}

/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}

/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSV. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and v in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSV representation
 */
function rgbToHsv(r, g, b){
    r = r/255, g = g/255, b = b/255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, v = max;

    var d = max - min;
    s = max == 0 ? 0 : d / max;

    if(max == min){
        h = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, v];
}

/**
 * Converts an HSV color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and v are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  v       The value
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hsvToRgb(h, s, v){
    var r, g, b;

    var i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    var f = h * 6 - i;
    var p = v * (1 - s);
    var q = v * (1 - f * s);
    var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

    switch(i % 6){
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

I found this **[here](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)**.

I also found **[hslpicker.com](http://hslpicker.com/)** which have what I want.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)

Comment: I already saw that. But I dont understand how to use them.

Comment: Just copy those functions and save in your js file and call them with args ? No special instructions man. Just give it a try.

Comment: I started learning javascript one month ago. So I dont know that much about pure javascript. I am learning jquery and jquery ui. I saw about JavaScript Function Parameters on w3school. But I don't know how to give  slider value as input.

Answer (score 2):

I've slight modified your fiddle. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/5n5v2ygb/

Brief description. I've move out similar code from all your slider's handler to two functions. One function set the color and appropriate fills two text field. This function, also, use hslToRgb.

```
function setColor(hue,sat,light,alpha) {
        var hsla = "hsla(" + hue + "," + sat + "%, " + light + "%, " + alpha + ")";
    var rgb = hslToRgb(hue/360,sat/100,light/100),
            rgba = "rgba("+rgb[0]+","+rgb[1]+","+rgb[2]+","+alpha+")";

            $("#slidevalue").text(hsla);
            $("#slidevalue-rgba").text(rgba);

            $(".slidevalue").css({
                "background-color": hsla
            });  

  }
```

Second one just call this function and replace the value of `slider.slide`

```
function handler() {
        setColor($('#range-slider1').slider('value'),$('#range-slider2').slider('value'),
                 $('#range-slider3').slider('value'),
                $('#range-slider4').slider('value'));  
  }
```

Comment: That's it except that you need to round the values for CSS rgba.

Comment: I know about rounding. But I'm a bit lazy, so I skip this part. This code is an example :)