# Javascript function to convert hsv to hex

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web application in which I'm using javascript color picker to pick a color. It is giving me color in form of HSV and i want to convert it into hex form.Can anyone help so that i pass HSV to a function which will return color in form of HEX.
Here is my code: I'm using a function of spectrum.js, which is not giving the proper output.

```
<script src="scripts/spectrum.js"></script>
$("#showInputWithClear").spectrum({
    showInput: true,
});
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: so what output are you getting from `spectrum.js` ?

Comment: [HSV to RGB conversion formula](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm), and similar (but not the same) question was on StackOverflow, [conversion of HSL to RGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/Automattic/Color.js to get the color.
Try the below code I hope, It'll help you.

```
<script src="https://github.com/Automattic/Color.js"></script>
function GetColorCode() {
     var hsv = $("#showInputWithClear").val();
     var c = Color( hsv );
     //  alert(hsv);
     c.toString();
    // "#0c2291"
}
```

Comment: thanks it works for me...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like spectrum.js has an option, `preferredFormat`, which will give you a hex code directly, instead of using an additional library. Here's an example:

```
$("#showInputWithClear").spectrum({
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    showInput: true,
});
```