# Java adjust lightness to color

Tags: java, colors, rgb, hsl

Let's say that I have a `Color`. I extract the `rgb` values.

Hypothetically

- r = 90
- g = 240
- b = 8

I also have the `L value` from `HSL`. Nothing else from HSL.

### Explanation of Lightness (L):

L var can take value from 0 to 1.

- If it's `>0.5` then it's brighter. //*1 is white*
- If it's `<0.5` then it's darker. //*0 is black*
- If it's `=0.5` then it's neutral.

So my question is:

**How can i change the rgb values using the L value?**

For example if L = 0.45 then the rgb values decrease a little.
Else if L = 0.8 the rgb values add alot.
Also i am coding in Java if it helps with the answear.

Comment: See [HSL to RGB color conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)

Comment: @Jesper this isn't what i wanted, look the answer below so you can understand what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

if `L < 0.5` then

```
r' = r - r * 2 * (0.5 - L);
g' = g - g * 2 * (0,5 - L);
b' = b - b * 2 * (0,5 - L);
```

else if `L > 0.5` then

```
r' = r + (255 - r) * 2 * (L - 0.5);
g' = g + (255 - g) * 2 * (L - 0.5);
b' = b + (255 - b) * 2 * (L - 0.5);
```

if `L = 0.5` the rgb values stay as they are.