# Converting 3 RGB ints to one 0-1 double

Tags: java, colors, type-conversion

I'm creating a GUI that has a `double` slidePos from 0-1 that needs to dictate the color of a setting. The resulting color should always be at full saturation and 50% brightness. I need to convert the number from 0 to 1 into any color(i.e. three ints), where 0 is red, 0.333 is green, and 0.666 is blue. I would also need the reverse operation, taking three integers and turning them into a double from 0-1. How would I go about the math to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate it on paper? Since it would make your life much easier when you recreate what you have written on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is simply a conversion from HSL to RGB and backwards. Take a look at the answer *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493060/2181949)*. For your case, `s=1` and `l=0.5`.