# Is it possible to get RGB from HEX color?

Tags: css

Is it possible to get R, G and B from HEX color in CSS?

For example if I have #00fbff I want to know RGB from this color (0, 251, 255), I'd like to know if it's possible to get the separate values. Because I'm trying to use HSL and, if I understand it well, I need these RGB values.

Comment: If you're trying to convert from HSL to RGB [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion).

Comment: As CSS is a declarative language, there's no way to "convert" between color formats *in CSS*. However, you can convert it by hand with [one of the many online converters](https://www.google.com/search?q=color+converter+online)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to retrieve the separate red,green, and blue values from a css color so basically:

```css
--my-color: #abcdef;
--my-color-red: /* Dynamic expression that evaluates to */ #ab0000 /* Based on var(--my-color) */;
--my-color-green: /* same as before but green */ #00cd00;
--my-color-blue: /* ... */ #0000ef
```

If this is what you want, then there currently isn't a way although there are 2 proposals:

1. [relative colors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors)
2. and [color-adust](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#coloradjust)
   which will solve your problem however they aren't available for use yet. In the mean time you could easily use a tiny bit of javascript to accomplish this

Comment: So, Javascript is the best solution

Comment: Yes for now I think JavaScript is the best solution. However I wouldn't be surprised if relative colors or color-adjust rolled into browser soon