# Change (RGBA) values to (HSl) after loading the pixels array in p5js

Tags: javascript, colors, p5.js, rgba

Hello all :) I am struggeling to change (RGBA) values to (HSL) after loading the pixels array.
I have loaded an image and want to change the colors on a HSL base, not RGBA.I have tried lots of approach but still no results... This color change must be on the fly... Maybe my approach is compleatly wrong please help.

```
        let img;
    let r,g,b;
    let h,s,l;
    let maxRGB;
    let minRGB;
        function preload() {
          img = loadImage('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1130743520/photo/branch-in-blossom-isolated-on-white-background-plum.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=XyQOr40sUU0xodn7zk-sNaMR-85_mRDImRPL4o4GvPY=');
        }
        
        function setup() {
          createCanvas(400, 400);
        }
        
        function draw() {
          background(220);
          image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
         let d = pixelDensity();
            loadPixels();
              for (let i = 0; i < height*d; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < width*d; j++) {
                var index = 4*(i+j*width*d);
          
                   r = pixels[index+0];
                   g = pixels[index+1];
                   b = pixels[index+2];
                
              
               maxRGB = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b);
               minRGB = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b);
                
                s = (maxRGB - minRGB) / maxRGB;
                l = maxRGB;
                
                var dr = (maxRGB - r) /
                    maxRGB - minRGB;
    
                var dg = (maxRGB - g) /
                    maxRGB - minRGB;
    
                var db = (maxRGB - b) /
                    maxRGB - minRGB;
    
    
      if (s == 0) {
        h = 0;
      } else if (r == maxRGB && g == minRGB ){
        h = 5 + db;
      } else if (r == maxRGB && g != minRGB ){
        h = 1 - dg;
      } else if (g == maxRGB && b == minRGB ){
        h = dr + 1;
      } else if (g == maxRGB && b != minRGB ){
        h = 3 - db;
      } else if (r == maxRGB ){
        h = 3 + dg;
      } else {
        h = 5 - dr;
      }
    
      h = h * 60;
    
STRUGGLING WITH PART TO CHANGE PIXELS FROM RGBA TO HSL
          

    }}
         
                updatePixels()
        }
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop, you have the `rgb` color of each pixel. you can use a function to convert `rgb` to `hsl`. I found [this one](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/rgb-to-hsl).

```js
let img;
let r, g, b;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage(
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1130743520/photo/branch-in-blossom-isolated-on-white-background-plum.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=XyQOr40sUU0xodn7zk-sNaMR-85_mRDImRPL4o4GvPY="
  );
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  const d = pixelDensity();
  loadPixels();
  for (let i = 0; i < height * d; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < width * d; j++) {
      const index = 4 * (i + j * width * d);

      r = pixels[index + 0];
      g = pixels[index + 1];
      b = pixels[index + 2];

      const [h, s, l] = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
      pixels[index + 0] = h;
      pixels[index + 1] = s;
      pixels[index + 2] = l;
    }
  }

  updatePixels();
  noLoop();
}

function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255;
  g /= 255;
  b /= 255;
  const l = Math.max(r, g, b);
  const s = l - Math.min(r, g, b);
  const h = s
    ? l === r
      ? (g - b) / s
      : l === g
      ? 2 + (b - r) / s
      : 4 + (r - g) / s
    : 0;
  return [
    60 * h < 0 ? 60 * h + 360 : 60 * h,
    100 * (s ? (l <= 0.5 ? s / (2 * l - s) : s / (2 - (2 * l - s))) : 0),
    (100 * (2 * l - s)) / 2,
  ];
}
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). A bit of a hack, but [`p5.Color`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Color) kinda does this already(but it's undocumented), e.g.  ```function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
  rgb = color(r, g, b);
  return [int(rgb._getHue()), int(rgb._getSaturation()), int(rgb._getLightness())];
}```.  I think exposing the formula for others to learn (instead of using an undocumented workaround) is better.

Comment: Hello  @Azadeh Radkianpour Thx for answering my question :) Maybe You know how can I manipulate of this image hue on the mouseX movement ?

Comment: @Michael This library is for making creative code. you can't expect these kind of questions to be answered.
If you want to use X Y position of mouse, you should check the p5js official reference: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseMoved

Comment: Hello @Azadeh First of all, thank you for your comment and hint on how to achieve the desired effect. Second, I know it's a creative coding library, but I wasn't creative at the time :) it's good that today I'm creative and figured out a way to achieve the desired effect ;) BR Michael