# How to convert Hex to RGB?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, hex, rgb

I am trying to use this to figure out if a color is light or dark

[Evaluate whether a HEX value is dark or light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754211/evaluate-whether-a-hex-value-is-dark-or-light)

Now. It takes in a `int`

```
 float calcLuminance(int rgb)
 {
      int r = (rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16;
      int g = (rgb & 0xff00) >> 8;
      int b = (rgb & 0xff);

      return (r*0.299f + g*0.587f + b*0.114f) / 256;
 }
```

I have a hex color though.

I tried to do this

```
  var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
  int rgb = color.R + color.G + color.B;
   var a = calcLuminance(rgb);
```

I got 0.11725 I thought it would have to be in the range of 0-256 or something like that.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to covert `R` to an `int`? Or am I just way off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am trying to use this to figure out if a color is light or dark

Just use [`Color.GetBrightness()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness.aspx)

---

**[Edit]**

> I want to determine if I should use white or black for my text.  So anything ≤ .5 I should use white and > .5 black?

There are a [number](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/902-Selecting-Contrasting-Text-Color-Based-On-Background-Color.htm) [of](http://colorusage.arc.nasa.gov/bkg_1.php) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946544/good-text-foreground-color-for-a-given-background-color/946734#946734) to determine what color to use on a given background, none of which are perfect.

That last link actually recommends using black/white only, but choosing a cutoff point of 0.73 instead of 0.5. I think you should just go with that, and change it if you find it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft-   so  something like this    System.Drawing.Color someColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
            float ab = someColor.GetBrightness(); Is there anyway to do this without converting it first to rgb?

Comment: @chobo2 Just `float ab = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF").GetBrightness();` :)

Comment: @Chobo:  Well, how are you *inputting* the color into the computer?  The example you gave **is** RGB:  in `"#FFFFFF"`, the first `"FF"` is the R *(in hexadecimal)*, the second `"FF"` is the G, and the third `"FF"` is the B.  As @lasseespeholt states in the comment above, you can get the brightness from your RGB-string in one line.

Comment: @lasseespeholt  - Cool. So I want to determine if I should use white or black for my text. So anything that is .5 and less should I use white and if greater than .5 I should use black?

Comment: Luminance and Brightness are not the same thing. I got better results using Luminance to determine if a color was dark or light

Comment: @chobo2: that would work, though values near 0.5 might not give good results using *either* black or white :)

Comment: @chobo2 I've no idea to be honest ;) I know nothing about colors and how humans interpret them => I do not know when it is best to switch or what method you should use to determine it :) I hope others can help you...

Comment: @ BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft  - hmm would you know how to choose a color for those?

Comment: @Magnus  - Hmm well I am looking for whatever will help me figure out what color to use for text color. Originally I was thinking it is either black or white but now I am not sure. I don't want to spend too long on this so I can only get it to figure out to use white or black and that is good for 80% of the cases then I will be happy with that. If someone knows how to get close to 100% good then I will go with that.

Answer (score 28):

Just convert the hex string to an integer:

```
int color = Convert.ToInt32("FFFFFF", 16);
```

Comment: Whoops, I upvoted this because I misread the question.  He is not actually asking "How to convert from hex to RGB" - what he really wants to know is how to get the brightness (luminance) of an RGB color.

Comment: He's got two different potential questions. "How to do x" and "Is there a better way than x". I answered the first one and you answered the second!

Answer (score 22):

You can use:

```
public string GenerateRgba(string backgroundColor, decimal backgroundOpacity)
{
 Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexBackgroundColor);
 int r = Convert.ToInt16(color.R);
 int g = Convert.ToInt16(color.G);
 int b = Convert.ToInt16(color.B);
 return string.Format("rgba({0}, {1}, {2}, {3});", r, g, b, backgroundOpacity);
}
```

**[Link To original Post by jeremy clifton on git](https://gist.github.com/jeremyclifton/8058522)**

Comment: Link To original Post not found!

Answer (score 4):

A little of topic, but here is an extension method to the Color struct I've created to calculate Luminance with different algorithms. Hope it helps you.

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the luminance of the color. A value between 0 (black) and 1 (white)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">The color.</param>
    /// <param name="algorithm">The type of luminance alg to use.</param>
    /// <returns>A value between 0 (black) and 1 (white)</returns>
    public static double GetLuminance(this Color color, LuminanceAlgorithm algorithm = LuminanceAlgorithm.Photometric)
    {
        switch (algorithm)
        {
            case LuminanceAlgorithm.CCIR601:
                return (0.2126 * color.R + 0.7152 * color.G + 0.0722 * color.B) / 255;

            case LuminanceAlgorithm.Perceived:
                return (Math.Sqrt(0.241 * Math.Pow(color.R, 2) + 0.691 * Math.Pow(color.G, 2) + 0.068 * Math.Pow(color.B, 2)) / 255);

            case LuminanceAlgorithm.Photometric:
                return (0.299 * color.R + 0.587 * color.G + 0.114 * color.B) / 255;
        }

    }

   /// <summary>
   /// The luminances
   /// </summary>
   public enum LuminanceAlgorithm
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Photometric/digital ITU-R
       /// </summary>
       Photometric,

       /// <summary>
       /// Digital CCIR601 (gives more weight to the R and B components, as preciev by the human eye)
       /// </summary>
       CCIR601,

       /// <summary>
       /// A perceived luminance
       /// </summary>
       Perceived
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as I see it, is your calculation of `rgb`. You add the values together which gives you a number between 0 and 3*255 which clearly isn't the value your method expect. You will have to calculate it like this

```
int rgb = (int)color.R << 16 + (int)color.G << 8 + color.B;
```

which should be equivalent to this (except for the alpha-value you don't use)

```
int rgb = color.ToArgb();
```

Lastly, as you can see in Chris Haas answer, you can skip this step by converting directly to an int.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is OK, but your function is wrong, correct one is here:

```
int rgb = Convert.ToInt32("#FFFFFF", 16);
var a = calcLuminance(rgb);

float calcLuminance(int rgb)
{
    int r = (rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16;
    int g = (rgb & 0xff00) >> 8;
    int b = (rgb & 0xff);
    return (r*0.299f + g*0.587f + b*0.114f) / 256;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert HEX to RGB **without using System.Drawing** with this :

```
 int RGBint = Convert.ToInt32("FFD700", 16);
 byte Red = (byte)((RGBint >> 16) & 255);
 byte Green = (byte)((RGBint >> 8) & 255);
 byte Blue = (byte)(RGBint & 255);
 //Color.FromRgb(Red, Green, Blue);
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5735950/3744182) by [Chris Haas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231316/chris-haas) already suggests using `Convert.ToInt32`: *Just convert the hex string to an integer: `int color = Convert.ToInt32("FFFFFF", 16);`*.

Answer (score 1):

The ranges of the `R`, `G` and `B` from the [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) struct are 0-255.

To get the rgb value you expect in your function, you will need to left shift accordingly:

```
int rgb = (int)color.R << 16 + (int)color.G << 8 + color.B;
```

Answer (score 1):

`calcLuminance` only returns a percentage.