# I wrote a HEX to RGB conversion in C#, and Crayon's library terminal console input/output can't understand the conversion method value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have seen the question [How to convert Hex to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735886/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb), but their answers were not what I looked for. I also have seen the following questions:

- [Convert ARGB hex string to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574084/convert-argb-hex-string-to-rgb)
- [How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

But I was not looking for these answers.

I use C#/Nuget library [Crayon](https://github.com/riezebosch/crayon) that allows me to define a colour for the console output using ANSI escape codes.

I wrote a small code in C# to convert the hexadecimal code colour to the RGB colour and I assigned the method value to Crayon's libray input/output.

```cs
static string HexToRGBColour(string hex) 
{
  int r = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(1, 2), 16);
  int g = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(3, 2), 16); 
  int b = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(5, 2), 16);
  
  return r + ", " + g + ", " + b;
}
```

I assigned the method and its value to the new variable:

```cs
var goldenYellow = HexToRGBColour("#B38D1E");
Console.WriteLine($"The RGB of #B38D1E is {goldenYellow}");
```

It resulted as `179, 141, 30` and it was correct.

It worked fully.

But I assigned them to Crayon's library `Rgb()` input/output and it failed.

The original code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{Rgb(179, 141, 30).Text("Preview of the colour")}");
```

It worked fully.

I wanted to get rid of the RGB, and use to the hexadecimal code instead. Here is the modified code with two alternatives:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{Rgb(goldenYellow).Text("Preview of the colour")}");
Console.WriteLine($"{Rgb(HexToRGBColour("#B38D1E")).Text("Preview of the colour")}");
```

The first code failed with a following error:

```
The error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'g' of 'Output.Rgb(byte, byte, byte)'
```

The second code failed with the same error.

I expected that both these codes would become `Console.WriteLine($"{Rgb(179, 141, 30).Text("Preview of the colour")}")`.

Remember I use .NET Core 8 and Linux and that I want to use an OS-agnostic code.

Comment: No, it becomes Rgb("179, 141, 30").  A string, not 3 ints.

Comment: I also have tried `static int[]`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You are right. I also tried `bytes[]` and it almost worked, but the code is not elegant for being too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HexToRGBColour()` method returns `string` whereas Crayon's `Rgb()` method expects three bytes.

Generally speaking, you can't easily pass the value as a single parameter to the `Rgb()` method since there are no overrides which can accept it.

What can you do is make an intermediate/extending method which will accept e. g. an array of three bytes or `System.Drawing.Color` struct, then call `Rgb()` method and return its output. And make your `HexToRGBColour()` method return the array/`Color`.

If you can't use the `Color` struct you can make your own similar struct.

Something like this (I haven't tested the code, it's just to illustrate the idea):

```cs
static Color HexToRGBColour(string hex) 
{
  int r = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(1, 2), 16);
  int g = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(3, 2), 16); 
  int b = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(5, 2), 16);
  
  return Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);
}

static IOutput Rgb(Color color){
  return Rgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused when you suggested me to call firstly `Rgb()` and then `HexToRGBColour()`. Do you mean `Console.WriteLine($"{Rgb(HexToRGBColour("#000000")).Text("Preview of the colour")}")`?

Comment: @Oo'- Exactly. With the additional method, which accepts the color as a single parameter, it will work.

Comment: @Oo'- I've looked more closely to the Crayon library and it seems the `Rgb` method returns `IOutput` not `Rgb`, so I've changed  the example a bit (return type of the our new `Rgb` method).

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine` is inside the `Main` method, but the static methods are outside the `Main`, and I received the error that the type or namespace name `IOutput` could not be found. If I move these methods inside `Main`, I received the two errors:  `No overload for method 'Rgb' takes 3 arguments` and the second error is the same about `IOutput`.

Comment: Add a proper `using` declaration for `IOutput` namespace, find it inside the Crayon library (or use IDE which can do this for you). This will tell the compiler where to search it. Based on your questions I'd recommend you to study a bit about how to do a C# programming, this is very basic things you're asking.

Comment: I had `using static Crayon.Output` enabled before. As you asked, OK!