# How to sort color codes from light to dark in Java

Tags: java, graphics, colors

Around 30-40 different colors that I use in my project. I'm holding hex codes of these colors on one array and displaying them on listview. Current listview colors are listed randomly.

However I want to sort these colors according their proximity from white to black.

current randomly listview link:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33ufll3&s=8#.VAiClfmSyXY

My code:

```
public void work(String sub){
       ArrayList<String> colorCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
         ArrayList<String> colorNames = new ArrayList<String>();
         ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         Field [] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields();
         String colorCode;
         String colorName;
         int color;

         final CustomList adapter2 = new CustomList(MainActivity.this,
                    add.colorArray);
         adapter2.clear();
            int number=0;           
            try
            {
                for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
                {                       
                    getResources().getColor(fields[i].getInt(null));

                    colorName = fields[i].getName();
                    colorCode = getResources().getString(fields[i].getInt(null));
                    color = fields[i].getInt(null);
                    System.out.println("COLOR:" +String.valueOf(color));

                    if(fields[i].getName().subSequence(0, 3).equals(sub)){
                    if(!colorCodes.contains(colorCode))
                    {
                        colorCodes.add(colorCode);
                        colorNames.add(colorName);
                        colors.add(color);
                    }            
                }
                }

            }
                catch (Exception ex){}


        number=0;  
        for(int i=0;i<colorCodes.size();i++){


                add.adding(colorCodes.get(i), number+1,colors.get(i));
                number++;     
           }


            add.doCustom(adapter2, (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1));
   }
```

Comment: Now what is the exect question? Where did you stuck? And since when are RGB codes made out of 8 hex digits?

Comment: So if you have a list of codes, you want them sorted, is that right? For example, if you have 000000, 999999, FFFFFF, 333333.. you want them in your list in the order of [FFFFFF,999999,333333,000000]?

Comment: yep, i already have list color codes, how i will sort them 000000 to ffffff? f=15 right? it will work for if i sort 00 00 00 00 00 00 to 151515151515 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that you would need two things: the list of colors (e.g., `List<Color> colors`) and some way of comparing colors according to how dark or light they are. (See : [Evaluate whether a HEX value is dark or light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754211/evaluate-whether-a-hex-value-is-dark-or-light) ).

For example, if we simply compare the sum of the RGB values (which may not be sufficient for your purpose), then the comparison order would be established by...

```
@Override
public int compare(Color c1, Color c2) {
  return Integer.compare(c1.getRed() + c1.getGreen() + c1.getBlue(), c2.getRed() + c2.getGreen() + c2.getBlue());
}
```

Then the actual sorting would simply be:

```
Collections.sort(colors, new Comparator<Color>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Color c1, Color c2) {
    return Integer.compare(c1.getRed() + c1.getGreen() + c1.getBlue(), c2.getRed() + c2.getGreen() + c2.getBlue());
  }
});
```

Here is an implementation based on luminescence:

```
    Collections.sort(colors, new Comparator<Color>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Color c1, Color c2) {
            return Float.compare(((float) c1.getRed() * 0.299f + (float) c1.getGreen() * 0.587f
                    + (float) c1.getBlue() * 0.114f) / 256f, ((float) c2.getRed() * 0.299f + (float) c2.getGreen()
                    * 0.587f + (float) c2.getBlue() * 0.114f) / 256f);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be the simplest approach, but not necessarily the most accurate.  For a more accurate approach, see my other answer.

Convert them to HSV and sort on V - which is a measure of how bright a colour is.  Note that the Java methods that use HSV call it HSB, just to be different.

Probably the simplest thing to do is to write a `Comparator` that calls the `RGBtoHSB` method of the `Color` class, and does its comparison on the third number in each result.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia page on HSL and HSV

> A more perceptually relevant alternative is to use luma, Y′, as a lightness dimension (fig. 12d). Luma is the weighted average of gamma-corrected R, G, and B, based on their contribution to perceived luminance, long used as the monochromatic dimension in color television broadcast. For the Rec. 709 primaries used in sRGB, Y′709 = 0.21R + 0.72G + 0.07B; for the Rec. 601 NTSC primaries, Y′601 = 0.30R + 0.59G + 0.11B; for other primaries different coefficients should be used.

so if accuracy is important, I would recommend that you write a comparator that calculates `0.21 * R + 0.72 * G + 0.07 * B` and compares on that.

Comment: hello, i m trying yours.  but how can i convert my int color code value to RGB code?  my codes like it,                                int color;                                                      Field [] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields();             color = fields[i].getInt(null);

Comment: Use `new Color(yourIntegerGoesHere)` to make a `Color` object, then call `getRed()`, `getGreen()` and `getBlue()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, colors in format `#xxxxxx` are organized acording with the "amount" of red (first two hex), green (two hex in the middle) and blue (last two hex).

So, if white is `#ffffff` and black `#000000`, then try sorting the colors by the average of these three numbers (sum the values for red, gren and blue and divide by 3)

Comment: Why divide by 3?  It won't change the sort order.

Comment: @DavidWallace because it would be the average of R G and B